# "I'm a Holmes' apprentice." Is this English correct?

Tags: genitive-construction

[image]

This panel is from a popular Japanese manga "Detective Conan" (a.k.a. "Case Closed" in English-speaking nations).  The protagonist, Conan, shouts "I'm a Holmes' apprentice!!" (He wants to say how good his deduction skill is.)

Is this English correct?  If so, why is there "a" before "Holmes'"?  I learnt that you don't add a determiner before a genitive and that you say "one of my books" instead of "a my book".

So I suspect the English used in the manga is incorrect simply because the Japanese editor didn't know much about English grammar.  Am I right?

Comment: I don't know why you think that. A genitive can be used as an attributive modifier within the nominal, compare "It's an old people's home".

Comment: I doubt you ever say "a Tom's book".  "Old people's home" works as one noun like "a driver's license."  You understand my question and are being captious, aren't you?

Comment: "Old people's home" is not an NP but a nominal where the determiner "an" is external to the nominal. I'm simply making the point that it is possible for attributive genitives to occur as modifier in NPs. Other examples with attributive genitives include "It's a [Sainsbury's catalogue]", "It's a [women's college]", "She goes to an [all girl's school]".

Comment: Do you mean that "a Holmes' apprentice" is correct?

Answer (score 4):

You're quite right: the English is wrong. He is either **Holmes's apprentice** (Holmes's *only* apprentice) or he is **a Holmes apprentice** (one among others).

Many people, including me, would say **Holmes'** isn't correct in any context. We say *Holmes's* house is on Baker Street, and we might say there are no Sherlock *Holmeses* nowadays, but **Holmes'** only exists in mistakes. But we argue about this regularly in English Language Learners.

Comment: I would happily write Jesus' name, Moses' staff, James' book, and I am quite certain these are not mistakes.

Comment: I've heard that on proper nouns, the final "s" is optional. I've also heard it's not. I think it's up to the style book being followed. I reword my sentence wherever possible to avoid having to choose

Comment: I think names from the ancient world are exceptions to the 'rule'. "Achilles's heel" sounds awful. So do "Moses's staff" and "Jesus's name". But Yeats's poetry, and Keats's, sound right to me. The London area is **St. James's** but we wouldn't add a _second_ apostrophe for its possessive. NUFC's football ground is in a district of Newcastle called St. James. It is pronounced **St. James's Park** but spelt **St. James' Park**!

Answer (score 0):

This is bad grammar.

Possessive adjectives and nouns with possessive "'s" are definite nouns, just like nouns with "the" in front, so you can never put "a" in front of one. It's like saying "*a the apprentice*", which is clearly wrong.

One correct way of saying it would be reordering it to, "*I am one of Holmes' apprentices!!*"